# Lambda causes unexpected token

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, lambda, error-handling

I'm having a problem because of lambda. It says that it has unexpected tokens but there are no helpful solutions in the debugger. I am new to programming and I have no idea what to do especially because in the tutorial I follow it's the same thing with no errors. The code and the screenshot are bellow. Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31ilL.png)

```
        when {
            getButtonText == "Edit Profile" -> startActivity(
                Intent(
                    context,
                    AccountSettingsActivity::class.java
                )
            )

            getButtonText == "Follow" -> {
                firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                        .child("Following").child(profileId)
                        .setValue(true)
                }

                firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                        .child("Followers").child(it1.toString())
                        .setValue(true)
                }
            }
        }

        getButtonText == "Following" ->  {

        firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                .child("Following").child(profileId)
                .removeValue()
        }

        firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                .child("Followers").child(it1.toString())
                .removeValue()
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Kotlin, but it seems to me that you have a little issue with your code block. From what I understand, "when" is a sorta switch/case statement, so I think you might have excluded `getButtonText == "Following"` from your main `when` block and it seems to interpret it as just an unused lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 } <<<< 

 getButtonText == "Following" ->
```

The marked bracket is closing the `when` block and should be removed. When using Android Studio you should be able to hit Ctrl+Alt+L to auto fix your formatting, including indentation. This will probably help you spot these kind of mistakes in the future